# In gridview Datakey field contains double value but retutns only integer part,how to get complete double value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datakey

I'm having Gridview in which two columns  I want to hide but need to acces their value so I keep them in dataKey

out of these two datakey field one is application fees..which contains values in double format,
now I want these values for calculation...so I used following method to get the values from datakey application fee

```
   double ApplicationFees =  double.Parse(GridApplicationsList.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString());
```

now for eg if  my application fees value is 220.75 in gridview but it gives me 220.0 with above code,
how do I achive complete double value from datakey

Comment: Why don't you compute this value, at source level? Instead of calculating this in the grid, calculate this maybe at database level?

Comment: actually i want to show them in grid  for each record and in grid I have checkbox..so whichever check is true I need to read that value and add and then show final amount in message

Comment: How about configuring the columns, as visible="False"? At runtime you can still access these values? You can also format them by expressions such as DataFormatString="{0:c}", for money.

Comment: This should work, tried it in my code and it worked. So are you sure the datakey contains for eg 220.75? Try to put a breakpoint before and after the method runs

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that you are referencing a wrong field from the `DataKeyNames` collection by saying `Values[1]`.

Since you're storing two columns in the `DataKeyNames` property, always try referencing them using by it's name rather than by it's index like below. In case if you are adding one more field to the `DataKeyNames` property in future then you don't have to change the code to update the index position for the keys.

```
double ApplicationFees =  double.Parse(GridApplicationsList.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["APP_FEES"].ToString());
```